# How to implement dark mode in BlueJ using Github link

Tags: github, bluej, lib, darkmode

I am new to programming and have been using the IDE BlueJ. I wanted to change to dark mode using the code given in this GitHub link:

https://github.com/t-ye/bluej-dark-theme

The instructions there say to "Replace path/to/BlueJ/lib/stylesheets with the stylesheets in this project". I'm not really sure how to do that. I've tried searching for files within my Mac Finder, but haven't found anything. I'm assuming this is a pretty easy thing to do because the instructions on the Github don't say much, but I'm just not sure how to proceed. Sorry if it's a dumb question!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First off locate the blueJ application in finder, and then right click(or control+click), and click "Show Package Contents", then navigate to Contents/Resources/Java/stylesheets, then look for a css file named "java-colors.css". You can then either replace the file as a whole with a predefined darkmode css file or manually edit the colours to your liking.

Comment: Cheers! My pleasure.